# Using OS in virtual-machine increases security?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, security, virtual-machine, anti-virus

I have question about security.
I don't know if it's good place to ask this question here.

Let's say I want work with money, trade it and so on..
And I have ubuntu on iron on my laptop, but I have there a lot stuff that actually I don't know If I don't have some malvares, because I play with theese things.
Is good to make virtual machine, for instance in VirtualBox, and only use it for money tradings, etc...

Don't forget that this virtualmachine will be under my Ubuntu on the hardware, which actually maybe has some viruses.. If it matters..

And which kind OS should I use on VM, Ubuntu, or some other Linux, or Windows with some paid/free antivirus, and which..

Thank you so much.

Comment: Lightweight Personal Security (LPS) is a Linux-based USB live distro that is a good choice for this purpose because it writes no information to either the USB flash drive or your hard drive and it erases everything when it shuts down. The name *LPS* is derived from its two main features: 1. It is *lightweight* and therefore fast and 2. It is a *security* OS.

Comment: karel yes, but when I don't want every time turn off my OS when I want to change and make with money. If I'm programmer for instance, and now programming something, I can't poweroff the system and start OS from USB. I wan't to program, and alongside programming sometimes checks if my market is good or bad, and such things...

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you could probably install the LPS iso in a VM. Also LPS stands for Lightweight Portable Security, not personal security.

Comment: I will try it and post here what happens

Comment: @karel but it will be still secure if it will in vbox under the my OS?

Comment: LPS official sites doesn't work. Sad story... any alternatives?

Comment: [How secure is VirtualBox for privacy/anonymity?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88684/how-secure-is-virtualbox-for-privacy-anonymity). You're right the LPS download link is down.

Answer (score 1):

In VirtualBox you have a couple of options in terms of securing your data within a virtual Drive

- You can encrypt your VM disk inside VirtualBox. You must always
  shutdown the VM with this option and not use Sleep, Hibernate, etc...
- You can use a third party encryption tool to encrypt all the VM files
- Lastly you could encrypt the Host system Disk

With all of these options you should not use the Host systems Sleep, Hibernate or suspend functions while the VM is up and running, instead you should always completely shutdown the VM when done.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, using a virtual machine on its own doesn't necessarily add any security. The best thing security wise about a virtual machine is that it is almost completely separate from the host machine. So if you get a virus on your host computer it probably won't be able to access anything inside the VM, and vice versa. Disk encryption, like apesa suggested, makes it even more difficult for anything on the outside to access the contents of the VM.

To really add security you would have to reserve the VM exclusively for financial transactions and use your host machine (or another VM) for browsing and everything else.

As has been suggested, a live linux distribution can also help. With a live distro. any kind of malware is erased when the machine reboots, which can limit the window of opportunity for a virus to do anything malicious.